nuances of こんなに　そんなに　あんなに
so, i know differences, but for some reason some examples contradict logic? first - あんなに食べたのにまだお腹が空いているの. shouldn't it have said "そんなに"? after all, it's not the distant past　and and the action was performed by the interlocutor.. second - 彼女がこんなに早く来るはずない. shouldn't it be "あんなに"? by "so early" do you mean early for me or should you determine here by who is doing the action after all (3rd person)?

Sorry, I can't understand what you're trying to ask, because you seem to be getting ahead of yourself in the explanation. It would help to start by showing where you got the examples from, what they supposedly mean (and according to whom), and give more steps to your logic for the correction.

@Karl Knechtel 1) I don't understand why あんなに, because it is used when something is distant from both interlocutors or familiar to both, something like what they both know, remember. should be "そんなに", because it is closer to the interlocutor? in the second example there is あんなに　emphasizes the adverb, but it is about a person who is not present during the conversation, so it is logical to put あんなに? or the logic is that the adverb "早く" is emphasized, so, because it's early for us, thats the point? maybe you're right and I'm just complicating things for myself

Distance is relative. Perhaps the 食べたの is being contrasted with more recent meals.

The expressions こんなに, そんなに and あんなに have clear distinctions.

こんなに refers to something happening nearby you, or something you're directly witnessing.
そんなに refers to something you've just heard from the conversation
あんなに refers to something you've experienced or seen in the past.

So, for example

こんなに食べたのに is used when you can directly see evidences that someone has eaten a lot -- like a pile of empty plates.
そんなに食べたのに is appropriate when you've just heard from someone that they have've eaten a lot.
あんなに食べたのに works when you've seen someone eat a lot in the past.

Therefore, the sentence "あんなに食べたのにまだお腹が空いているの" is correct if you witnessed someone eat a lot earlier.
"そんなに食べたのにまだお腹が空いているの" also make sense if you've heard someone ate a lot.
Regarding "彼女がこんなに早く来るはずがない," it makes sense if you are seeing her arrive early right now.
However, "彼女があんなに早く来るはずがない" contains a grammatical error because あんなに refers to something from the past, so 来るはずがない (present or future) should be in past tense. A better sentence would be "彼女があんなに早く来たはずがない."

It seems that your answer is unfinished or truncated. It ends with A better sentenc.

@Arfrever Thank you for letting me know. I edited my answer.

@Takashi so if its about who we are talking to, its better to use そんなに, based on "maggie sensei"' article - Talking to the person who is close to you about their actions:
Ex. そんなに食べたら太るよ. Or take my example お前はそんなに食べたのに.. its good?

@saenai I could not find the article you mentioned, but you are correct if you are talking to someone and replying what you've just heard.

@Takashi A little clarifying question, with your permission? :D - 1) If I want to tell a friend: you came so early yesterday. It would be 昨日はあんなに早く来た ? 2) if I have now heard from a friend his story about the distant past, I answer -そんなに面白い話.. ?

@saenai Yes, both sentences are correct usage.

@Takashi Sorry to come back with a question again) Iあんなに雨が降ると思わなかった　 is this okay? After all, we thought in the past. or "konna", since the rain is in front of us? i found this grammar so difficult to understand it, sadly

@saenai "あんなに" refers to something in past, while "こんなに" refers to something that is happing right now. So "あんなに雨が降るとは思わなかった"  is correct if you are refering the past. If it keeps raining as heavy as before, you also can use "こんなに" as well. Never mind about asking a question. That is what you should do in this website :)

@Takashi "refers to something that is happening right now." so, in my example, this rule applies in the sentence part - 雨が降る or 思わなかった。　as far as I understand, 雨が降る。
